# SQL Lite Max value with other values

Tags: sqlite

I have table caled Amounts that has these values

```
ID Name Amt
1  John 5000
2  Ali  2000
3  Cath 7000 
4  Tom  4000
```

I want to find the difference between the highest amount and each Amount

It is easy to do in SQL Server as the query should be like this

SELECT ID, Name, Amt, Max(Amt) - Amt AS Diff FROM Amounts

which gives the result of

```
ID Name Amt  Diff
1  John 5000 2000
2  Ali  2000 5000
3  Cath 7000 0 
4  Tom  4000 3000
```

but when I try the same query in SQL Lite it only returns one row the max one

```
ID Name Amt  Diff
3  Cath 7000 0
```

how to do that in SQL Lite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to find the max value and then do the comparison:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Amt,
    (SELECT MAX(Amt) FROM Amounts) - Amt AS Diff
FROM Amounts;
```

If your version of SQLite happens to support analytic functions, then we can use `MAX` as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Amt,
    MAX(Amt) OVER () - Amt AS Diff
FROM Amounts;
```